# Better rand() API

Tags: c++, c++11, random, library

I use this document as a basis for my mini-library:

> ## Motivation
>
> The `std::rand` friends are discouraged in C++14, so we want:
>
> - A direct replacement to the `std::rand` friends. Despite of the security issues, `std::rand` is considered both handy and useful as a
>     global uniform random number generator.
> - To expose the most widely-used combo in C++11 `<random>` without pushing the users to learn the whole design. Smoothing the learning
>     curve can usually optimize the acceptance.that using `rdtsc`
>
> ## Design Decisions
>
> `std::rand` is a self-contained interface, so its replacement should
>   be independent as well. In addition, I expect the interface to
>   correctly expose the functionalities of `<random>` and lead to more
>   robust and secure programs. The proposed replacement is
>
> - Distribution based. RNG must be used with a distribution; `std::rand` is a wrong design.
> - Randomly seeded before used. Improper seeding like `rand(time(0))` may result in vulnerabilities.
> - Per-thread engine. Minimal interface should minimize astonishment, [with respect to] thread-safety and performance.
> - Manually seedable. User can observe repeatability in a given thread, which is a typical demand for debugging.
> - Type-safe. No integral promotion, no loss of distribution property during down-casting. For a given invocation, the inputs and the result
>     have the same type.

Questions:

- Do I follow the spec well? Primarily worried about 32-bit vs 64-bit issues.
- How can I do the ugly `enable_if` better?
- How can I do the ugly macros better?
- Good way to seed? Neither `rdtsc` or `std::random_device` are very portable.

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <type_traits>

/* rdtsc
 *
 * The instruction measures the total pseudo-cycles since the processor
 * was powered on. Given the high frequency of today's machines, it's
 * extremely unlikely that two processors will return the same value
 * even if they booted at the same time and are clocked at the same
 * speed.
 */

// GCC macros (Clang also supports these)
// https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Machine-Constraints.html
#if defined(__i386__)
    std::uint_fast32_t rdtsc(void)
    {
        std::uint_fast32_t tick;
        __asm__ __volatile__("rdtsc":"=a"(tick));
        return tick;
    }

    #define RTDSC_ENTROPY rdtsc()    
#elif defined(__x86_64__)
    std::uint_fast64_t rdtsc(void)
    {
        unsigned int tickl, tickh;
        __asm__ __volatile__("rdtsc":"=a"(tickl),"=d"(tickh));
        return ((std::uint_fast64_t)tickh << 32)|tickl;
    }

    #define RTDSC_ENTROPY rdtsc()
// MSVC (Visual C++)
#elif defined(_WIN64)
    #include <intrin.h>

    // returns 64-bit unsigned integer
    #define RTDSC_ENTROPY __rdtsc()
#endif

namespace better_rand
{

namespace detail
{
    /*
     * std::default_random_engine may default to a weak PRNG. In MSVC, it's
     * std::mt19937. In libstdc++ and libc++, it's std::minstd_rand0.
     *
     * Comparison (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/boost_random/performance.html)
     * shows that std::mt19937_64 potentially performs slower     
     */
    using random_engine = std::mt19937;

    // We only use a 64-bit seed with std::mt19937_64
    template <typename Engine = random_engine>
    typename std::enable_if<
        std::is_same<Engine, std::mt19937_64>::value,
        random_engine::result_type 
    >::type
    seed()
    {
        #if defined(RTDSC_ENTROPY)
            return RTDSC_ENTROPY;
        #else
            // std::random_device's result_type is unsigned int
            std::random_device rd;
            std::uint_fast64_t value = rd();
            value = (value << 32) | rd();
            return value;
        #endif
    }

    // 32-bit engine, 32-bit seed
    template <typename Engine = random_engine>
    typename std::enable_if<
        !std::is_same<Engine, std::mt19937_64>::value,
        random_engine::result_type 
    >::type
    seed()
    {
        #if defined(RTDSC_ENTROPY)
            return RTDSC_ENTROPY;
        #else
            // std::random_device's result_type is unsigned int
            return std::random_device(){};
        #endif
    }    

    // Global generator
    random_engine& prng()
    {
        thread_local static detail::random_engine re{detail::seed()};
        return re;
    }

    template <typename IntType>
    IntType randint(IntType a, IntType b)
    {
        // does not entirely satisfy 26.5.1.1/1(e).
        static_assert(std::is_integral<IntType>(), "not an integral");

        using distribution_type = std::uniform_int_distribution<IntType>;
        using param_type = typename distribution_type::param_type;

        thread_local static distribution_type d;
        return d(detail::prng(), param_type(a, b));
    }

    void reseed()
    {
        detail::prng().seed(detail::seed());
    }

    void reseed(detail::random_engine::result_type value)
    {
        detail::prng().seed(value);
    }
}

// Public API
using detail::randint;
using detail::reseed;

}

int main()
{
    using namespace better_rand;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        std::cout << randint(1, 10) << " ";
    std::cout << "\n";

    reseed(0);
    // Should output 6 6 8 9 7 9 6 9 5 7
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        std::cout << randint(1, 10) << " ";
    std::cout << "\n";

    reseed();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        std::cout << randint(1, 10) << " ";    
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Are you referring to http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4316.html ?

Comment: `rdtsc` is not portable at all (only Intel x86/x86_64 chips have it, not even Itanium). `std::random_device` is mandated by the standard, and even on implementations that don't provide cryto-grade random_device, they're probably better than picking from a monotonous source.

Answer (score 5):

It's not clear to me why we need to downgrade from `std::random_device` to a timestamp-based seed on Intel platforms.  If we have good reason to distrust a particular library's implementation, then submit a patch mixing timestamp into the randomness, rather than ignoring the platform's randomness.

C++17 was standardised after this code was written; it provides `if constexpr` to simplify the two versions of `seed()`:

```
template <typename Engine = random_engine>
auto seed()
{
    std::random_device rd;
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<Engine, std::mt19937_64>) {
        std::uint_fast64_t value = rd();
        value = (value << 32) | rd();
        return value;
    } else {
        return rd();
    }
}
```

The implementation here still embeds an assumption that `std::random_device::max` is 2³².  A more portable version adapts to the actual sizes of the random device and engine, perhaps like this:

```
template <typename Engine = random_engine>
auto seed()
{
    using result_type = typename Engine::result_type;
    std::random_device rd;
    result_type result = 0;
    auto const step = rd.max() / 2 + 1;
    auto const start = std::numeric_limits<result_type>::max();
    for (auto needed = start;  needed;  needed = needed / 2 / step) {
        result = result * 2 * step | rd();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Here, `needed` keeps track of how much more needs to be generated, and `step` represents how much is added from the device in each iteration (divided by 2, to make it an exact power).

---

With C++20 Concepts, we can replace the `static_assert` in `randint()` with a constraint:

```
template <std::integral IntType>
IntType randint(IntType a, IntType b)
{
```

---

The thread-local engines could be problematic in some applications.  It's important that the user be aware that `reseed()` applies only to the calling thread's instance, and does not affect any other.

---

Given that many calls would like to use the same distribution, it would be nice to have an interface that returns a combination of generator and distribution, that can be used as a source of numbers drawn (with replacement) from a single population.  That seems like a useful enhancement.

Answer (score 3):

Some things to think about: different PRNG algorithms have different trade-offs. The MT19937 algorithm is very fast, but it has a huge internal state (19937 bits to be exact, which is how it got its name). While this is a trivial amount of memory on desktop and server class CPUs, consider that on devices with less (cache) memory, this can be a significant drawback.

And related to the internal state, ideally you should use a [seed sequence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/seed_seq) of at least 19937 bits to seed the `std::mt19937` engine.

Finally, why have two versions of `seed()`, one specifically for `std::mt19937`, one for any other engine? That does not make sense at all.